# How do I merge multiple resource bundles?

Tags: java, properties, merge, resourcebundle

I have a resource bundle which consist of a few files, lets say:

- `address_en_us.properties`
- `address_nl_nl.properties`
- `address_fr_ca.properties`

How do I obtain and merge two of the properties file with `en_us` being the 'default' property file?

Some background:

When I use one of the localized property, say, `fr_ca`, for each keys that are not localized in `fr_ca`, I want to use the default value specified in `en_us`

Answer (score 4):

Just rename your "address_en_us.properties" to "address.properties" and this file is always used as 'default' property file.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have seen work is to have the default values set in code, where it is hard-coded in java class. That way any property not set in properties file but used in code will always get the default value.

And from an architecture perspective this is also a really good idea, shipping products with default properties values in code, overridden by the values in properties file. And if you make it so that the product (Android app in my perspective) makes a server call at start-up to check and overwrite the values of properties files then you can add a lot of flexibility to the product.